# NextJS dynamic slug for route

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to do the following in NextJS?

```
/route1
/translatedRoute1
/route2
/translatedRoute2
```

Having this folder structure

```
pages/
  [route1]/
    index.js
  [route2]/
    index.js
```

This will give an error because [route1] and [route2] will will both match in all circumstance.
The idea is that I want to render the same component for both English and Romanian.

```
/about-us
/despre-noi

-> I want this to render the same component as "/about-us"

This can be achieved with

/en/about-us
/ro/about-us

But this is not the desired effect.
```

The desired effect is to change the slug for different languages

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use some plugins as such an advanced configuration is not available out of box.

This seems to me like what you need:
https://github.com/vonschau/next-routes-with-locale#how-to-use

Comment: I managed to find a workaround for my specific use case, but thanks a lot :)!

Comment: @EmanuelCengher could you post how you solved it ?

Comment: @EmanuelCengher what did you do to solve this problem? I have a similar question